# TOpenPictureDialog não pega o caminho da pasta Imagens

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo

Tenho no meu formulário um componente `TOpenPictureDialog` para abrir as Imagens em um sistema, só que em vez dele pegar o caminho completo do arquivo de imagem ele pega apenas o alias.
Ex

- **Como eu preciso      :** '*C:\Users\Usuário-03\Pictures\Arquivo.jpg*'
- **Como o ele está vindo:** '*Imagens\LOGO CMR.Jpg*'

Já tentei ver todas as opções nos em [Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenOptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenOptions) e [Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenOptionsEx](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenOptionsEx) e não achei nada... Como posso fazer isso?

***Imagem de como está vindo***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
procedure TfrmManutencaoParametros.opdParametrosSelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Muda a imagem no Quadro de imagens
  if opdParametros.FileName <> '' then
  begin
    inherited;
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ImgLogo.Picture.LoadFromFile(opdParametros.FileName);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Está tentando extrair o caminho com qual propriedade? Usando `OpenPictureDialog1.FileName` no Delphi 7 (versão que tenho), retorna o caminho todo como vc precisa + o nome do arquivo... Se funcionar na sua versão, é só extrair o nome do arquivo...

Comment: Coloque seu código para termos mais detalhes.

Comment: @Melissa, estou utilizando OpenPictureDialog1.FileName

Comment: Edu, coloca o código completo

Comment: @RobertodeCampos ai o código completo...

Comment: Você já tentou montar um projeto simples para ver se da o mesmo problema? Porque só com esse peço de código não da para verificar onde está o erro. E colocar mais código só vai deixar sua pergunta poluída.

Comment: já sim: e também já verifiquei em fóruns para ver se achava um resposta e nada.

http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=85939&sid=ff049e947038cab60a0cab989c285b4a

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está um exemplo de como eu uso esse componente. `Dir` é uma variável que eu crio para jogar o nome do diretório.

-- Início --

```
if Dir = '' then
begin
  Dir := 'C:\';
end else
begin
  OpenPictureDialog1.InitialDir := DIR;
end;

OpenPictureDialog1.Execute;
Edit1.Text := ExtractFileName(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName);
Dir := ExtractFilePath(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName) + Edit1.text;
Edit1.Text := Dir;
```

-- Fim --

Caso não dê certo, favor informar aqui o erro para que eu possa ajudar.
O componente também possui uma propriedade chamada `InitialDir`, tente colocar o caminho padrão do diretório lá caso ele não for mudar.

Comment: Isso ai eu já sei e já estou fazendo só não está trazendo o caminho correto.

Comment: Desculpe pela pergunta "boba" (estou sem pc no momento então não posso testar isso exatamente agora e nunca pensei em testar o que vou perguntar), mas você já tentou escolher o caminho "C:/usuario/imagens/..." ou está indo direto para pasta imagens pela biblioteca? Nunca testei para ver se comportam de maneira diferente nesses dois caminhos.

Comment: estou indo direto na pasta pois não faz sentido para o usuário ir fazendo a rota completa.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
uses ...
  System.Types, System.IOUtils;

...
...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  Dlg: TOpenPictureDialog;
begin
  Dlg := TOpenPictureDialog.Create(Self);
  try
    with Dlg do
      begin
        InitialDir:= TPath.GetPicturesPath;
        if Execute then
          Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      end;
  finally
    Dlg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Realmente não sei o que está acontecendo, não sei se é coisa do Delphi CE ou do meu pc não sei... voltou a dar erro... 

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda...